# Faster way to search in list (created from json rows)

Tags: python

I have a 2 list of dicts like this (get it as json from requests.json()):

```
[
  {'Key': '8382194d-67b0-11ec-99c3-ac1f6bf6e43f', 'Data': '.....'},
  {'Key': '8c0e5cc1-686e-11ec-99c3-ac1f6bf6e43f', 'Data': '....'},
  {'Key': '64f6198f-6919-11ec-99c3-ac1f6bf6e43f', 'Data': '....'},
  ...
  # there is 40,000+ more items
]
```

One from local source, one from remote. I need to know what elements are gone from remote source, what elements are added and where Data is changed (so to keep local source synced with remote). My current code look like this:

```
def findByKey(Key, arr):
    elems = [item for item in arr if item['Key'] == Key]
    if len(elems) == 0:
        return None
    return elems[0]


localList = requests.get(local).json()
remoteList = requests.get(remote).json()

    for localItem in localList:
        remoteItem = findByKey(localItem['Key'], remoteList)

        if remoteItem is None:
            print('We should delete item in local list with Key', localItem['Key'])
            # call delete function

        if remoteItem['Data'] != localItem['Data']:
            print('We should update item in local list with Key', localItem['Key'])
            # call update function

    for remoteItem in remoteList:
        localItem = findByKey(remoteItem['Key'], localList)

        if localItem is None:
            print('We should create item in local list with Key', localItem['Key'])
            # call create function
```

Because 2 lists is large (40,000+ items in each), this function take around 2 minutes to cycle through all items, but I want to get changes in this lists as quick as it possible.

I think it's very slow. Not because Python but because I wrote un-optimized code. (I'm a at very beginning of learning Python)

How this code can be optimized for better performance?

Comment: I suggest you convert them to pandas dataframes. It has optimized methods to do things like this.

Comment: It would also be better to change the list to a dictionary, so you can look up by key efficiently. Searching 40,000 items every time will be extremely slow.

Comment: If the keys within each list are unique, then converting each one into a dictionary would be a better approach than using pandas if you are just learning Python. Doing so would make doing the what you want to do very fast.

Comment: convert the json into some dict data structure, so search won't need iterating?

Comment: Might be worth posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @martineau, thank you very much Execution time dropped from 160s to 0.2s in dict instead of list.

Comment: @Barmar thank you very much, converting list to dict dropped execution time in 830x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After applying the  solution from @martineau and @Barmar - converting list to dictionary with unique keys - execution time dropped from 166 seconds to just 0.2 seconds (830x) and I can get rid of additional function.

So now my code looks like this:

```
local = {item['Key']:item for item in localList}
remote = {item['Key']:item for item in remoteList}

for localItem in local.values():
  remoteItem = remote.get(localItem['Ref_Key'], None)

# and so on
```

Thank you all kindly!

Comment: Impressive performance gain!

Comment: @martineau all thanks to you! :)